# Anyone know who made this bike? See head badge pic

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

[image]

Can anyone help identify this Bike? I could not find a manufacturer stamp or date only the headbadge and Suntour accessories. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The badge was used by Raleigh on their Rampar (Ralpar in the UK) range from 1972 until at least the early 1980s.

- [Velobase](http://velobase.com/ListHeadBadges.aspx?BrandView=e71b2612-32a3-428c-8928-f69dafcd853c) shows this exact badge about two-thirds of the way down the page and says "1970s".
- [The Headbadge](http://www.kurtkaminer.com/TH_ralsport_visID.html) shows the design in use as a seat tube decal from 1972–82.

<sub>I found this with a Google image searches for something like "vintage bicycle R head tube badge". I struck lucky just as I was about to give up and post a comment suggesting you do the search.</sub>

Comment: Yeah, the hardware bits are identical to my old 72 Raleigh, though I don't remember that badge.

Comment: And the brakes locate the bike around 1970.